# Appending lists into a list of lists in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell

All I've been able to find in the documentation that are relevant are ++ and concat.

I thought at first doing the following would give me what I wanted:

```
  [1, 3, 4] ++ [4, 5, 6]
```

but as you know that just gives [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].

What would I need to do to take in [1, 2, 3] and [4, 5, 6] and get out [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]?

Comment: Just use `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`?  If `x = [1, 2, 3]` and `y = [4, 5, 6]`, then `[x, y]` is what you're looking for.  Keep in mind that the `[a, b, c]` syntax is just sugar for `a:b:c:[]`, so you could also write this as `[1, 2, 3] : [4, 5, 6] : []`.

Comment: To clarify I'm looking for a function do this to an arbitrary number of lists and in the context of recursion.

Comment: Haskell's type system doesn't allow vararg functions (aside from some deep magic that allows the Text.Printf function to work), so what you're looking for can't exist and would be poor practice anyway.

Comment: Are you able to picture to yourself how would you like to use this functionality? If yes, show us.

Comment: According to your comment  you want to take a list of list and yield it a list of lists. So basically it sounds like you're looking for `id` specialized to `[[a]] -> [[a]]`. Unless I misunderstood, you might want to re-identify the problem you're wanting to solve.

Comment: @Silvio Mayolo Sorry I misspoke - I don't need a function to do this to an arbitrary number of lists, I just want to use it multiple times to create a list of an arbitrary number of lists. To make things absolutely clear, I'm thinking of a function f taking in some [a], [b] and outputting [[a], [b]].

Comment: @MasterMastic I just did an recursive implementation and found out that it was actually behaving like `id` after reading your comment. :)

Comment: @ThroatOfWinter57 Then you can do `[a]:[b]:[]` just like how @bheklilr said. Example: `[1,2,3]:[4,5,6]:[]`

Comment: Just to wrap it together: `conc a b = a:b:[]`.

Comment: If you use `f x y = [x,y]` you have `f [a] [b] = [[a],[b]]`, but then you can not add a new list using `f`. E.g. `f [a] (f [b] [c])` will not work if `a,b,c` share their types. You have to do `[a] : f [b] [c]`, but then why not using `[a]:[b]:[c]:[]` or, on a recursive call `[a] : myRecCall (n-2)` ?

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in comments, a function to take two lists and combine them into a new list can be defined as:

```
combine :: [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]
combine xs ys = [xs,ys]
```

This function can't be applied multiple times to create a list of an arbitrary number of lists. Such a function would take a single list and a list of lists and it would add the single list to the list of lists, so it would have type:

```
push :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
```

This is just `(:)`, though:

```
push = (:)
```

As also mentioned in the comments, the value `[x,y]` can also be written as `x : y : []`.<sup>1</sup> Since both cases can be done with `(:)`, I would guess that what you really want to use is `(:)`, sometimes consing onto `[]` and sometimes onto a non-empty list.

---

<sup>1</sup> In fact, `[x,y]` is just [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for `x:y:[]`.

Answer (score 1):

think about what the (++) operator does: it *concatenates* Lists, it does not construct them. This is how it concatenates text Strings into a new String (and not a list of Strings), since Strings are lists of Chars. to construct a new List out of Lists you use (:) like so:

```
[1,2,3]:[4,5,6]:[]
```

where youre adding each list *as an element* of a new list.