# Variadic list appender function to make a list of lists from lists in haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284836/appending-lists-into-a-list-of-lists-in-haskell) for how to take multiple lists and turn them into a list of lists.  I have the following:

```
Prelude> x1 = [1,2,3]
Prelude> x2 = [4,5,6]
Prelude> x3 = [7,8,9]
```

I'd like to see some \function where this could be variadic:

```
Prelude> xs = map (\function -> ???) x1 x2 x3
Prelude> show xs -- that produces this
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

Or without map, some other variadic function F such that:

```
Prelude> xs = F x1 x2 x3 ... x1000
Prelude> show xs -- that produces this
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], ...., [1000000,1000001,1000002]]
```

My expectation from the answer was that something like

```
Prelude> map (:) x1 x2 x3 []

<interactive>:26:1: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Integer]
                                    -> [Integer] -> [a0] -> t’
                  with actual type ‘[[Integer] -> [Integer]]’
    • The function ‘map’ is applied to five arguments,
      but its type ‘(Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer])
                    -> [Integer] -> [[Integer] -> [Integer]]’
      has only two
      In the expression: map (:) x1 x2 x3 []
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = map (:) x1 x2 x3 []
    • Relevant bindings include it :: t (bound at <interactive>:26:1)
```

or

```
Prelude> map (:) $ x1 x2 x3 []

<interactive>:27:11: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Integer]
                                    -> [Integer] -> [a0] -> [a]’
                  with actual type ‘[Integer]’
    • The function ‘x1’ is applied to three arguments,
      but its type ‘[Integer]’ has none
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘x1 x2 x3 []’
      In the expression: map (:) $ x1 x2 x3 []
    • Relevant bindings include
        it :: [[a] -> [a]] (bound at <interactive>:27:1)
```

I failed to find this kind of function in Hoogle as well, but probably misspecified the type signature:

https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5B%5Ba%5D%2C%5Ba%5D%5D

Comment: What's wrong with `[x1, x2, x3]`?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, but it would be cool if I could do it without commas and enclosures. Is that impossible?

Comment: It is possible, but certainly not Haskell-idiomatic. You should at least explain why you want this.

Comment: Why would `map` have any sort of use here? I'm really not clear on what your goal is.

Comment: @AJFarmar, I added a portion above showing that map not required for the question.  Thank you.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I really like when I'm writing Haskell places where I can use a dollar sign to mean 'everything to the right of here' rather than write parenthetical enclosures.  I guess what I was hoping for in a variadic list-append-all-the-following-stuff-of-the-same-type function was similar behavior so that I could not use [enclosure, braces, and, commas].  It's minor and aesthetic, and non-idiomatic, but I wanted to understand.  Even if the operator were kind of ugly, like `[$` and saved almost no typing, would be interesting to me. :)

Comment: Hmm, like a generalization of `$`?  Like some kind of `([] . $)` composition analogy?

Comment: Well, if you just want to avoid brackets then use `x1 : x2 : x3 : []`. But that can't possibly work without any infixes, because juxtaposition by itself is always function application in Haskell. Note that a variadic function could actually **not** be used with `$`, because it's parsed as `((f x1) x2) x3`.

Answer (score 5):

Polyvariadic functions in Haskell are quite hard to achieve. This is because a function can fundamentally only have one argument, and hence further arguments are included only through currying, which bakes the number of arguments into the function's type.

However, that doesn't mean it's impossible, though sometimes this requires the use of extensions. Here I will go through a few, in increasing order of complexity. This probably won't be very useful, but maybe helpful.

Somewhat tangentially, a few years ago I made [a respository of examples of polyvariadic functions](https://github.com/AJFarmar/haskell-polyvariadic), which you might find interesting, but which are fairly same-y and of dubious quality; I'm no professional even now, and that *was* a few years ago.

---

### Method 1: Using seperate functions (No extensions)

A simple but crude method of doing this would simply be to define multiple functions to make a list with *n* elements, such as:

```
makeList1 :: a -> [a]
makeList2 :: a -> a -> [a]
-- etc.

-- Use:
myList = makeList5 1 2 3 4 5
```

This isn't so fantastic. Can we do better?

---

### Method 2: Typeclasses (Requires `FlexibleInstances`)

This is much more interesting. Here, we sacrifice specificity to create a truly polyvariadic function:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

class MkIntList r where
  mkIntList' :: [Int] -> r

-- No arguments
instance MkIntList [Int] where
  mkIntList' = id

-- One argument, then some others
instance (MkIntList r) => MkIntList (Int -> r) where
  mkIntList' xs x = mkIntList' (xs ++ [x]) -- (Inefficient, but this is an illustration)

-- The variadic function
mkIntList :: (MkIntList r) => r
mkIntList = mkIntList []

-- Use:
myList1 = mkIntList 1 2 3 :: [Int] -- myList1 = [1,2,3]
myList2 = mkIntList :: [Int]       -- myList2 = []
```

I'll leave you to get your head around this one.

---

### Method 3: Functional Dependencies (Requires `FlexibleInstances` and `FunctionalDependencies`)

This is a polymorphic version of the previous one, in which we must keep track of the type via a functional dependency.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}

class MkList a r | r -> a where
  mkList' :: [a] -> r

instance MkList a [a] where
  mkList' = id

instance (MkList a r) => MkList a (a -> r) where
  mkList' xs x = mkList' (xs ++ [x]) -- (Again inefficient)

mkList :: (MkList a r) => r
mkList = retList []

-- Use:
myList1 = mkList 'H' 'i' '!' :: String -- myList1 = "Hi!"
myList2 = mkList True False :: [Bool]  -- myList2 = [True, False]
```

I make a slightly [more efficient version of this](https://github.com/AJFarmar/haskell-polyvariadic/blob/master/src/List.hs) code a while ago.

---

### Method 4: Metaprogramming (Requires Template Haskell)

This I think is the least theoretically interesting of the solutions, so I won't go into the frankly tedious examples.

This method involves creating a function which in turn generates Haskell code, via Template Haskell, which one can then use to generate the necessary function, based on the length of this list, at compile time. This is essentially a less labour-intensive (but slower at compile time) version of method 1.

---

Nowadays there are probably far more ways of doing this, but I hope that you find these examples helpful, or in the very least enlightening.

Comment: Wow! I never want to see this in a code base I touch, but it's cool to finally see a use case for fundeps that "makes sense"!

Comment: @TeoKlestrupRöijezon Glad I could help. As it happens though, this this a simplified version of the method used in [the `printf` implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Text.Printf.html#printf). If you understand this, you'll find `printf` quite an interesting read.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to write my own answer based on [the Varargs wiki page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Varargs) (which describes how printf implements it) and almost had it working, but I never made the connection to add the fundep.

Comment: This is neat.  Is there any form of 3 that also wouldn't require explicit type coercion of " :: String" but just infer the type in that they are all the same?

Comment: @Mittenchops I'm afraid not. You must specify the type (or make it inferrable), otherwise the result could be, for instance, of type `Char -> Char -> String`, but maybe you want that.

Answer (score 2):

Mainly, the reason your approach isn't working is that (I think) you have slightly misunderstood `map`. Let's have a look at the type signature:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

You can see here that the main restriction with `map` is that only one list is passed in as a parameter - so you can't pass multiple lists, which is what you have tried to do. The other reason this doesn't work is that `map` is specifically for applying a function to the elements *within* a list, and you're trying to use it *between* multiple lists, without changing the individual elements.

So how can you define your function? The problem here is that Haskell doesn't really support variadic functions (but see below). In Haskell, if you want to support any amount of arguments of the same type, you would join them together in a list; that is, `fn [a, b, c]` instead of `fn a b c`. So let's try that here: your function would be:

```
fn :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
fn = ???
```

So how do we implement this? What we want is a function which combines multiple lists, and we're given a list containing multiple lists (the arguments), so... the output is exactly the same as the input! At this point, we're probably better off ignoring `fn` - or indeed any attempted `map (:)` combination - and just writing the list ourselves. So your example would just be:

```
xs = [x1, x2, x3]
```

If even this doesn't work for you, and you really do want a variadic function, then I would suggest looking back over your program and checking whether it's using the best/easiest approach - remember the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

(Side note: if you *really* need it, and there's *no* way to solve your problem otherwise, then it is actually possible to define variadic functions in Haskell - search `Haskell variadic function` for more information. However, this approach is mostly useful when doing string formatting or advanced type-level stuff, making it unlikely that you would need such an approach.)

Comment: Thanks.  This is not something I /need/ or have a "use case" for, just something I was curious how to do.  I'll search for that query you gave to understand this.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Some good examples of variadic functions 'in the wild' can be found at https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.0/base-4.12.0.0/Text-Printf.html and https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.0/threepenny-gui-0.8.3.0/Foreign-JavaScript.html#v:ffi. Basically, you give a function a type of `MyFnTypeclass r => r`, but then you define `MyFnTypeclass` such that it has instances `param -> x`, `param1 -> param2 -> x` etc., so you can give it any number of arguments.

Comment: Ooh, that is neat.